# Ruby 2.1.2's Regexp.new behaves differently in console and when run in Rails Server

Tags: ruby, regex

I use Ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) and Rails 4.1.7

I want to check this kind of string for `.en.` or `.de.`:
`8a118a8a485481d401493d0ae7ad7fba.en.3`
`8a11y48sf85481d401493d0ae7a37fba.de.1`

I need to have the en/de part as string replacements: `"#{@language}"`

I use this Regex in rails console:

```
Regexp.new("\\.#{@language}\\.") # @language = 'en'
# => /\.en\./
```

This is what I want to get. This is right.

In my class I use this method:

```
def entry_is_of_language?(guid)
  lang_regexp = Regexp.new("\\.#{@language}\\.")
  guid.scan(lang_regexp).any?
end

# => /\\.en\\./
```

Why does the method inside my class escapes the backslashes but the console doesn‘t do it? Any idea?

**Edit:**
To answer @mudasobwa’s remark, this is the output of @language:

```
def entry_is_of_language?(guid)
  lang_regexp = Regexp.new("\\.#{@language}\\.")
  p "-- #{@language} -- #{lang_regexp} --"
  guid.scan(lang_regexp).any?
end

# => "-- de -- (?-mix:\\.de\\.) --"
```

**But here’s the strange part: It works.**
In my opinion the output of the Regexp is wrong when writing it in the server’s log. But the actual result is correct. It filters the right languages. I don’t necessarily understand what is happening here, but it works?!

Comment: Probably not the cause of your error, but you can use string interpolation in regular expression literals, i.e. `/\.#{@language}\./`

Comment: Are you sure you compare them with the same methodology? Can you show us how do you check for value (puts? inspect?)

Comment: @MBO I judged from the output in my server log and the output in my console. They looked different from each other. As they apparently aren’t different though, I am stumped a bit. But it does work in the end. Perhaps the rails log has its own escapes for printing regular expressions? I don’t know.

Comment: @HolgerFrohloff: But output in logs can use different method (just `#to_s`, `#puts` to file or any other method you use), and output in console is just`#inspect`, or you can use `puts` to display value... They can output values differently! Compare `puts rx` with `puts rx.inspect` (`p rx` is similar to `puts rx.inspect`) - irb console doesn't `puts` values strictly speaking, but displays output of calling `#inspect` on value and displays returned string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m pretty sure the problem is with `@language` variable not properly defined. Below is a test on my `2.1.2-95` box:

```
guid='8a118a8a485481d401493d0ae7ad7fba.en.3'

class B
   attr_reader :language
   def initialize
     @language = 'en'
   end 
   def entry_is_of_language?(guid)
     lang_regexp = Regexp.new("\\.#{@language}\\.")
     puts "Using #{lang_regexp}"
     guid.scan(lang_regexp).any?
   end 
end
B.new.entry_is_of_language? guid

# ⇒ Using (?-mix:\.en\.)
# ⇒ true
```

Would you mind to `puts @language`?

There is a difference between `p` and `puts` also:

```
▶ p "\\."
# ⇒ "\\."
▶ puts "\\."
# ⇒ \.
```